# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ed3' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: yolo, yolov8

I'm using the following code:

from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("weights/best.pt")

And I'm getting the following error:

WARNING  Ultralytics settings reset to defaults. This is normal and may be due to a recent ultralytics package update, but may have overwritten previous settings.
View and update settings with 'yolo settings' or at 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Ultralytics\settings.yaml'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Tai lieu\Đồ án\test_yolov8.py", line 1, in 
from ultralytics import YOLO
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics_*init*_.py", line 5, in 
from ultralytics.hub import start
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\hub_*init*_.py", line 5, in 
from ultralytics.hub.auth import Auth
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\hub\auth.py", line 5, in 
from ultralytics.hub.utils import HUB_API_ROOT, PREFIX, request_with_credentials
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\hub\utils.py", line 14, in 
from ultralytics.yolo.utils import (ENVIRONMENT, LOGGER, ONLINE, RANK, SETTINGS, TESTS_RUNNING, TQDM_BAR_FORMAT,  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from . import v8
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\v8_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from ultralytics.yolo.v8 import classify, detect, pose, segment
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\v8\classify_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from ultralytics.yolo.v8.classify.predict import ClassificationPredictor, predict
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\v8\classify\predict.py", line 5, in 
from ultralytics.yolo.engine.predictor import BasePredictor
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\engine\predictor.py", line 37, in 
from ultralytics.nn.autobackend import AutoBackend
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\nn\autobackend.py", line 17, in 
from ultralytics.yolo.utils import LINUX, LOGGER, ROOT, yaml_load
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\utils_*init*_.py", line 755, in 
SETTINGS = get_settings()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\utils_*init*_.py", line 718, in get_settings
yaml_save(file, settings)  # save updated defaults
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\utils_*init*_.py", line 264, in yaml_save
yaml.safe_dump({k: str(v) if isinstance(v, Path) else v
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml_*init*_.py", line 269, in safe_dump
return dump_all([data], stream, Dumper=SafeDumper, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml_*init*_.py", line 241, in dump_all
dumper.represent(data)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line 28, in represent
self.serialize(node)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\serializer.py", line 54, in serialize
self.serialize_node(node, None, None)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\serializer.py", line 107, in serialize_node
self.serialize_node(key, node, None)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\serializer.py", line 89, in serialize_node
self.emit(ScalarEvent(alias, node.tag, implicit, node.value,
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\emitter.py", line 115, in emit
self.state()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\emitter.py", line 412, in expect_block_mapping_simple_value
self.expect_node(mapping=True)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\emitter.py", line 244, in expect_node
self.expect_scalar()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\emitter.py", line 268, in expect_scalar
self.process_scalar()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\emitter.py", line 533, in process_scalar
self.write_plain(self.analysis.scalar, split)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yaml\emitter.py", line 1132, in write_plain
self.stream.write(data)
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1258.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ed3' in position 6: character maps to

What can I do to fix this?